# Is there any reason to wait for DOM Content to load before calling async functions?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, event-handling, dom-events

I'm learning Javascript and VSC kind of just suggested that I make my fetchElements function asynchronous and changed it for me automatically but I'm looking at where I was calling it and it seems like it might be pointless to have an asynchronous function wait for DOM content to load. I'm still working on getting a handle on asynchronous functions, fetch and all those things, so I just want to get some input from those who understand this stuff more. Is it pointless to wait for DOM Content to load before calling an asynchronous function?

`fetchElements()` itself does not rely on any DOM content but it does return a function that does.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  fetchElements();
});

async function fetchElements() {
```

Comment: What is the `fetchElements` function?

Comment: Does your async function depend on any DOM elements that are not yet  loaded?  Would loading the DOM elements first improve your users' perception of your website's performance?

Comment: Whether the function is async or not doesn’t really matter.  If it uses dom elements you should wait for the dom to load.

Comment: good point, I will edit the post to include that information

Comment: No. but you may have a reason to wait in the callback